# Water won't come back on after turning main back on

Tags: water, shower

I turned off the water at the main cutoff valve in the garage to replace the gaskets in a single handle shower faucet.  I got it put back together but when I turned the water back on, I get nothing anywhere in the house.  Checked the meter and it is not moving at all. Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Further information.  It is a gate valve and I'm pretty sure it's the original that came with the house which is about 17 years old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the main valve a gate valve?  If so, you'll probably have to replace it. These types of values often fail when not used for a long time, and either won't close or won't open again after being closed.

You may be able to repair the valve, but you'll have to shut the water off to do that, so you might as well just replace it with a new valve.  If fact, you should replace it with a ball valve (aka quarter turn valve). Ball valves are more reliable, and typically don't break from not being used.

Comment: It is a gate valve.  Edited question to add this information

Comment: Bad gate valve was indeed the problem. New ball valve installed.

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing happened to me after a simple sink repair. Went a day and a half without water.  Plumber said it was an older type valve, just needed to be backed off a quarter turn.  Disaster averted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/137099)